# How to set different edge colors for valid values (pcolormesh)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to highlight the edge of grids whose values are valid.

Here's an example.
The value of yellow grids is 2 while it's 1 for the purple grids.
The purpose is to plot the edges of them in different colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.full([5, 5], np.nan)

# grids with value = 1
z[1, 1] = 1
z[0, 2] = 1
z[1, 3] = 1

# grids with value = 2
z[3, 1] = 2
z[3, 2] = 2
z[3, 3] = 2

plt.pcolormesh(z)
plt.pcolormesh(z, edgecolors='red', facecolors='none')
```

[image: example]

Goal:

[image: goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through Z and draw a rectangle at each of the positions it's not NaN. The rectangles have width and height of `1`; `clip_on=False` can be used to avoid that the rectangles are partly clipped away near the plot borders.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = np.full([5, 5], np.nan)

# grid cells with value = 1
z[1, 1] = 1
z[0, 2] = 1
z[1, 3] = 1
# grid cells with value = 2
z[3, 1:4] = 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(z, cmap='Pastel1')
for i in range(z.shape[0]):
    for j in range(z.shape[1]):
        if not np.isnan(z[i, j]):
            color = 'dodgerblue' if z[i, j] == 1 else 'crimson'
            ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((j, i), 1, 1, fc='none', ec=color, lw=3, clip_on=False))
ax.axis('off')  # hide axes
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.colormesh with some cells highlighted]

For your new question, with irregular boundaries, the code could look like the following.  Note that the number of cells in each dimension is one less than the number of boundaries.  Also note that the order of the parameters for `Rect` are still `Rect((x,y),width,height)` and that `pcolormesh` still plots the contents of `z[i,j]` at the `i`'th row and `j` 'th column. `np.meshgrid` takes care of the ordering.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1d = np.random.uniform(1, 3, 9).cumsum()
y1d = np.random.uniform(1, 3, 7).cumsum()
x, y = np.meshgrid(x1d, y1d)

z = np.random.randint(0, 3, (x.shape[0] - 1, x.shape[1] - 1)).astype(float)
z[z == 0] = np.nan

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='spring')
for i in range(z.shape[0]):
    for j in range(z.shape[1]):
        if not np.isnan(z[i, j]):
            color = 'dodgerblue' if z[i, j] == 1 else 'crimson'
            ax.add_patch(
                plt.Rectangle((x[i, j], y[i, j]), x[i, j + 1] - x[i, j], y[i + 1, j] - y[i, j],
                              fc='none', ec=color, lw=3, clip_on=False))
ax.axis('off')  # hide axes
plt.show()
```

[image: pcolormesh with irregular boundaries]

Comment: Thanks! If I have three same-shape arrays named x, y, and z, the plotting function is `plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z)`. I tried `plt.Rectangle((x[i, j], y[i, j), xwidth, ywidth)` and it works well! Note that the order of `i, j` is different from your example. Maybe, it's better to update the answer with this more complicated example? Thanks.